# How would I detect if a user is pinged in discordpy, even in a reply

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Had a quick question regarding discordpy that was giving me a bit of a headache.
Does anyone know how to detect if a user is mentioned, even in a reply ping?

I know how to detect if a user is pinged with an @, but I had no idea where to start on detecting reply pings.

[image: reply ping]

apologies for no code snippets, I had no idea where i would even begin to fix this issue

thanks!

[image: Screenshot of someone else's bot]

Comment: note - I do believe that bot was coded in java

Comment: what do you mean didnt you code it?

Comment: @yotamrec it's another bot and he wants to do the same thing

Comment: oh ok @stijndcl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#message) class has a mentions attribute so combined with an [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) should do the trick if

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message:discord.Message):
    print(message.mentions)
```

Answer (score 0):

It look's like either the message sender or the member mentionned have a role named: "Don't mention"

So if you want to duplicate this, you need to check if sender/recipient has that role. I'm not going to code it for you, I'll help you out if you edit your questions and add a startup :)

Comment: yes, but role detection is not my issue.
my issue is checking when a user is mentioned via a reply ping.